# Changing Font for an enitre Android App?

Tags: android, button, fonts, textview

Is there any way to change the font for an entire Android application ? I'm aware of changing the font for each TextView and Buttons. I just wanted to know if there's a more elegant way of doing it since the program i'm working on has tons of layout files :(

Comment: you make custom Button and TextView classes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, depending on how much control you need:

1) You can create a custom style attribute in styles.xml, something like:

```
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

Keep in mind that this is a pretty limited approach, style may not contain everything you need.

2) You can create subclasses of TextView and Button and put your styling code in their constructors. I'd recommend this way because you can use whatever custom assets you might need. (I just saw that Nasser beat me to a code sample for this, check it out - it looks right)

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! Thanks to @Yoann Hercouet too :)

Comment: Glad to help! Actually I'm thinking of always starting my new apps from now on with subclasses of at least TextView, Button and EditText so that if <style> fails I wouldn't have to refactor all of my code...

Comment: That's generally a good practice when you start developing from scratch. The app i had to work on already had lots of layouts already built, and i wanted to get this done with the least amount of changes to the ones already present.

Answer (score 1):

to Apply same font effect through out the app you need to create your own custom TextView and Button class which has applied your custom font. and the use them in your layouts as normal views.

```
public class MinnesotaTextView extends TextView{

    public MinnesotaTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            textViewProprties(context);
        }
    }

    public MinnesotaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            textViewProprties(context);
        }
    }

    public MinnesotaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            textViewProprties(context);
        }
    }

    private void textViewProprties(Context context){
        Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica.ttf");
        setTypeface(tfs);
        setMaxLines(4);
    }
}
```

here's Button:

```
public class MinnesotaButton extends Button {

    public MinnesotaButton(Context context){
        super(context);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            buttonProprties(context);
        }
    }

    public MinnesotaButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            buttonProprties(context);
        }
    }

    public MinnesotaButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode()){
            buttonProprties(context);
        }
    }

    private void buttonProprties(Context context){      
        setPadding(0, 4, 0, 0);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_red_btn);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        setTextSize(13.0f);

        setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "garreg.ttf");
        setTypeface(tfs,1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that you can change fonts through custom textviews. What i was wondering was, if it is possible to change the font of the entire application without having to change each and every texviews and buttons ?

Comment: i think its not possible. you need to search android developer site for more information about such requirment.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with several attributes related to your theme to modify the default font colors on your application.

Here is an example for the theme Holo Light, you have to first change your manifest file to call your custom theme, and then customize your custom theme in the file styles.xml.

Here is the part of the manifest file you need to change to call your custom theme (the custom theme called here is `AppTheme`:

```
<application
    android:name="YourApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Then in your file `styles.xml`, create and customize this custom theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

These 3 parameters `textColorPrimary`, `textColorSecondary` and `textColorTertiary` will impact elements/components all over your application.